# Detect Hardware Volume Button Clicks When Screen Is Off

Tags: android

I've written an Andoid app that uses the hardware Volume buttons for another purpose.

It works fine if the app is running and visible, but when I turn the screen off or let it time out, the button clicks don't get into my handlers.

Does anyone know if there is a way to detect these button clicks when the screen is off?

Comment: How were you able to detect the button click when the screen was on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35168869/1293492

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep detecting things like this when the screen is off is to acquire a WakeLock that will allow the screen to turn off, and still let your app function. However, this drains the battery life quite a bit, and should only be used when absolutely necessary.

In this case, you will need a [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK).

Comment: i tried this, but it doesnt detect the buttons :( , any workaround ?