# Using volume buttons in app when phone is locked

Tags: java, android

I use the volume buttons in my app to scrolls through XML values. The phone vibrates depending on the given XML value. Is it possible to use the volume buttons in my app even when the phone is locked, and how?

Comment: This is the [link][1] you can refer but these thing are dangerous to use.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118976/recognize-volume-button-presses-when-screen-is-off-android