# Catch back button press event when screen locked

Tags: android

I am trying to write a small app that will catch the `KeyEvent` of the back button been pressed, **when the screen is locked**.
I saw that you can easily override `onKeyDown` or `onBackPressed` in order to catch this event, but this will work only if the activity is running.
As I understand on some of the android phones, if not on all of them, the OS doesn't listen to the back and menu buttons while the screen is locked.

**EDIT**
I have read couple of posts about capturing the event of the user pressing the volume buttons, and all says their isn't a way to do so when the screen is off.
Is their a reason to belive the case is change regarding the back button?

- [Check volume button usage when screen is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262040/check-volume-button-usage-when-screen-is-off)
- [Detect Volume Button Press when Screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277164/detect-volume-button-press-when-screen-off)
- [Detect Hardware Volume Button Clicks When Screen Is Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019335/detect-hardware-volume-button-clicks-when-screen-is-off)

Comment: So first you need to find  the screen locked  or not inside a service

Comment: Most phones these days have no active back button when the screen is off. They have on screen navigation (nav bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Register with BroadCast Receiver for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON

2) Check if Screen is locked using Keyguard Manager like :

```
KeyguardManager kManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean isLocked = kManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

or without using BroadCast Receiver, you can check like :

```
KeyguardManager kManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( kManager .inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //locked
} else {
 //not locked
 }
```

Next Check for back Button Press event if screen is locked.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
   //Back Button is pressed
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```