# Turn off light after 30 second of inactivity

Tags: java, android

My app is set LCD always on but it loses too much power, I want to dim or turn off LCD light(no sleep or lock) after 50 seconds of inactivity.

I tried some solutions but no one cant cures my problem.

I just want it on one activity, not others.

Please help me with any class or method that I can use for this

Edited:

My main problem:

I want to use hard key of an android device when it locked.

So now tell me,How can i use a hard key as a click in my app when screen locked???

Edit:

i have a device with 5 hard key and i want use them when device locked down.

Comment: _Hey mate plese update your question with code and more information_

Comment: what kind of information need you?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001592/7360848

Comment: this answer is good, but android dont let us use that permission anymore .so that answer cant help me

Comment: What's your minSdk?

Comment: api 19 android kitkat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping the screen on forever is as simple as creating a `wakeLock`. Turning off the screen after sometimes (probably 30 seconds or so) will be enabled by default in almost all the Android devices.

I think what you are looking for here is an app that behaves like a media player app/ music playing app. You can do so by running a service in the foreground. You will need to create a persistent notification for this. This way, your app/ activity will not get killed even if the device screen is off.

Find the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground

EDIT #1
As discussed in the comments, this link was helpful to the OP for getting the answer to his query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29818026/3811983

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i already use foreground service and unkillable notification.
now i want use buttons for app when android locked.it is my main problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand what do you mean by 'buttons for app'?

Comment: I have a device with 3 Hard key that i want use them when device go to sleep...

Comment: Understood. I'm looking for an answer for you. In the meanwhile, I request you to kindly upvote my answer so that it encourages me to help you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I appreciate you, but i cant do it because i need 15 reputation for doing this, help me with this issue and i will accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29818026/3811983

Comment: YES MAN, its work for me. Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could be of your help :) Thanks for marking it as the right answer. I'll edit it to include the link.