# Android app with camera shutter onkeyevent when screen is locked or off

Tags: java, android, camera, screen, keyevent

I made an app that uses the onkeyevent functions to capture the bluetooth camera shutter buttons with up and down volumes.  I am trying to use it for a camera app to take pictures when the screen is off.

However this no longer works if the screen is locked or off. The minute the screen is back on the function works again.  So I know the bluetooth is still connected.

Can anyone with experience in this tell me if it's possible for the phone to capture bluetooth events when the screen is off.  What changes should I make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch back button press event when screen locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817702/catch-back-button-press-event-when-screen-locked)

Comment: I have started using services now with mediasession and have hit a few more problems as listed in my questions.  Thank you for taking a look